# Heroku FreeTDS, how to use Rasil SQL Server with TinyTDS with Multi Buildpacks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, freetds, tiny-tds

I have to use the "Tiny TDS" gem with my Rails 4.2.3 and of course on cedar-14 of Heroku I can't because FreeTDS is not anymore on it.

How to use FreeTDS on Heroku cedar-14?

I'm looking on the web and I found this:

https://github.com/foraker/heroku-buildpack-freetds

He says to use this with "heroku-buildpack-multi", this one: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

but I don't understand how!

I have to create on my local pc the ".buildpacks" file?

and then I have to "git push heroku master"?

This procedure still work today?

Or I have to use this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Please help me, thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I found how to install FreeTDS on Heroku using this:

```
https://github.com/eltiare/heroku-buildpack-freetds
```

with this:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
```

with this .buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/eltiare/heroku-buildpack-freetds.git#master
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#master
```

But now, after the deploy, I got an error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/tiny_tds-0.6.2/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so (LoadError)
```

and the app crash.

**How to fix?**

These are the logs:

**Deploy**:

```
Deleting 2 files matching .slugignore patterns.
Fetching custom git buildpack... done
Multipack app detected
Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/eltiare/heroku-buildpack-freetds.git
=====> Detected Framework: FreeTDS
Installing freetds into /tmp/build_5e53a70f18da19be7f6defafbfad826b/vendor/freetds
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Writing FreeTDS configuration for subsequent buildpack
Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
Detected Framework: Ruby
Compiling Ruby/Rails
Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.6

WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Updating git://github.com/rails/turbolinks.git
       Updating git://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf.git
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies......
       Using rake 10.4.2
       Using i18n 0.7.0
       Using json 1.8.3
       Using minitest 5.7.0
       Using thread_safe 0.3.5
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using mini_portile 0.6.2
       Using rack 1.6.4
       Using mime-types 2.6.1
       Using arel 6.0.2
       Using execjs 2.5.2
       Using bcrypt 3.1.10
       Using sass 3.4.16
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Using cancancan 1.12.0
       Using net-ssh 2.9.2
       Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using chunky_png 1.3.4
       Using multi_json 1.11.2
       Using rb-fsevent 0.9.5
       Using ffi 1.9.10
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using cocoon 1.2.6
       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Using htmlcompressor 0.2.0
       Using rubyzip 1.1.7
       Using nprogress-rails 0.1.6.7
       Using pg 0.18.2
       Using puma 2.12.2
       Using rack-cors 0.4.0
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Using videojs_rails 4.12.6
       Using rdoc 4.2.0
       Using tzinfo 1.2.2
       Using rack-test 0.6.3
       Using warden 1.2.3
       Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
       Using autoprefixer-rails 5.2.1.1
       Using uglifier 2.7.1
       Using mail 2.6.3
       Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Using net-sftp 2.1.2
       Using compass-core 1.0.3
       Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
       Using sprockets 2.12.4
       Using wicked_pdf 0.11.0 from git://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf.git (at master)
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Using sdoc 0.4.1
       Using activesupport 4.2.3
       Using loofah 2.0.2
       Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1
       Using compass 1.0.3
       Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using globalid 0.3.5
       Using activemodel 4.2.3
       Using jbuilder 2.3.1
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
       Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
       Using activejob 4.2.3
       Using active_model_serializers 0.9.3
       Using activerecord 4.2.3
       Using carrierwave 0.10.0
       Using actionview 4.2.3
       Using carrierwave-ftp 0.2.8
       Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.2.4
       Using acts-as-taggable-on 3.5.0
       Using ancestry 2.1.0
       Using actionpack 4.2.3
       Using actionmailer 4.2.3
       Using railties 4.2.3
       Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
       Using htmltoword 0.4.2
       Using kaminari 0.16.3
       Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Using responders 2.1.0
       Using jquery-rails 4.0.4
       Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
       Using sass-rails 5.0.1
       Using rails 4.2.3
       Using turbolinks 3.0.0 from git://github.com/rails/turbolinks.git (at master)
       Using devise 3.5.1
       Using compass-rails 2.0.4
       Using rails-jquery-autocomplete 1.0.1
       Using chosen-rails 1.4.2
       Installing tiny_tds 0.6.2
       Bundle complete! 42 Gemfile dependencies, 90 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (12.85s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing tiny_tds (0.6.3.rc1)
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       cp public/assets/chosen-sprite-ea6754a5be024d46e1d1723d932957a5.png public/assets/chosen-sprite.png
       cp public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x-de4f9a7206a168caffa4500adc0de88b.png public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png
       Asset precompilation completed (6.59s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
Using release configuration from last framework (Ruby).
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for Multipack -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compressing... done, 62.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v10
```

**After Deploy**:

```
Release v10 created
2015-07-28T08:50:51.966282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-07-28T08:50:55.675410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-07-28T08:50:56.531068+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-07-28T08:50:59.423445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-07-28T08:51:02.826292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 30210 -e production`
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762029+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/tiny_tds-0.6.2/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so (LoadError)
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762058+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762060+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762061+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.2/lib/tiny_tds.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.2/lib/tiny_tds.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762066+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762069+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762070+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762067+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762074+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762078+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762083+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762075+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762085+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762079+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762088+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762096+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762090+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-28T08:51:06.762093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-28T08:51:07.545701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-28T08:51:07.566686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**UPDATE**:

if I run `heroku run bash` and I go here:

```
cd /vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/tiny_tds-0.6.2/tiny_tds/
ld tiny_tds.so
```

I have this:

```
ld: warning: libsybdb.so.5, needed by tiny_tds.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_iv_get'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbgetuserdata'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_ll2inum'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbresults'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbconvert'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_raise'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_exc_new_cstr'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsettime'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_cObject'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcmd'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsetlversion'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbinit'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_ary_entry'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_cTime'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_enc_associate'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_eval_string'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_scan_args'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcanquery'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_num2int'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_hash_aref'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_funcall'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_obj_freeze'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsetuserdata'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `ruby_xfree'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbclose'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_ary_new'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `tdsdbopen'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_data_object_alloc'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_enc_find'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcancel'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbmsghandle'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcount'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_thread_blocking_region'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_ary_new_capa'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsetlname'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbnumcols'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbdead'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_Rational'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbhasretstat'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_hash_aset'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `ruby_xmalloc'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_check_type'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsqlsend'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_yield'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbtds'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_string_value_ptr'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsetlogintime'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbnextrow'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsqlexec'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbloginfree'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_gc_mark'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_iv_set'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbfreebuf'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbuse'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_str_new_cstr'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_cRegexp'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsetversion'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dberrhandle'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_define_method'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbdata'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_const_get'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_global_variable'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbretstatus'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_enc_from_encoding'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbdatecrack'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_exc_raise'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_define_protected_method'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_float_new'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcoltypeinfo'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbdatlen'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_define_alloc_func'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_define_module'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_str_new'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbrows'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dblogin'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcolname'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbcoltype'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_warn'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_define_class_under'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_intern2'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_obj_call_init'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `dbsqlok'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_str_intern'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_ary_store'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_fix2int'
tiny_tds.so: undefined reference to `rb_hash_new'
```

what is this:

**libsybdb.so.5** ?

**ANOTHER UPDATE**:

I tried also to change the download url to:

```
https://fossies.org/linux/privat/freetds-0.95.19.tar.gz
```

but nothing, the same error:

```
LoadError: libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_77614230336e05e686009861d71719ea/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/tiny_tds-0.6.2/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue has been faced by others. Check out [this particular procedure](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/74#issuecomment-4528748) that seems to have worked.